# ScrollView isn't working properly

Tags: android

My ScrollView isn't working properly I am not able to scroll the whole view I've tried adding and removing weights but it's not working can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong? Below is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/referfriend_screen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/refersharemessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Share your referal code with a friend and earn Rs. 150/- for every share that translate to a sale" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/yourcode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:text="Your Code" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sharecodeWhatsapp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edit_text"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
               >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sharecodeWhatsapptext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Whatsapp Invite" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/shareCodeFacebook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edit_text"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/fb_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sharecodefacebooktext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Facebook Invite" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/shareCodeMore"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edit_text"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/more_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sharecodemoretext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="More Apps      " />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/referCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/item_view_add_to_cart_click"
        android:text="YTH45T"
        android:textColor="@color/white_bg" />


</RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am not able to scroll my whole view

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/referfriend_screen" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/refersharemessage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:padding="0dp"
                            android:text="Share your referal code with a friend and earn Rs. 150/- for every share that translate to a sale" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/yourcode"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                            android:text="Your Code" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/sharecodeWhatsapp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edit_text"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"

                                android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/sharecodeWhatsapptext"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"

                                android:text="Whatsapp Invite" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/shareCodeFacebook"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edit_text"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"

                                android:src="@drawable/fb_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/sharecodefacebooktext"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"

                                android:text="Facebook Invite" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/shareCodeMore"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edit_text"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:src="@drawable/more_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/sharecodemoretext"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:text="More Apps      " />

                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <Button

                    android:id="@+id/referCode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_view_add_to_cart_click"
                    android:text="YTH45T"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_bg" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am checking this it' is working... When your device need scroll than scroll work.....(Mean if Device contain your all content in first view than scroll not work otherwise it 'is work)

Answer (score 0):

Remove LinearLayout and make Relative layout a direct child of scrollview and it will start scrolling.